# Media query removes float: but does not set text width:auto on small screens

Tags: css, media-queries

Here is the media query:

```
@media (max-width: 480px){
html {font-size: 100%;} 
.column.third, .column.two-thirds 
{float: none;
width: auto;}
```

These are the styles for the divs referenced in the media query (I'm not sure if this is effecting things, but I included the CSS of the container div the columns are nested in).

```css
.column {
    display: block
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    .column.two-thirds { width: 66.7%; }
    .column.third { width: 33.3%; }

.container {
     max-width:1000px;
     margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
     width:90%;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
     overflow:hidden;
     background-color: white;
    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">>    
    <div class="column two-thirds">
      Hello World!      
    </div>
    <div class="column third">
      Hello World! 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question, actually?

Comment: Can you please provide a little more description of what you're trying to accomplish and what results you're getting? This is pretty vague. I recommend [this blog post by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule".

Comment: When the screen size is reduced to 480px, I would like the columns to stop floating left (making them stack on top of each other) and I would like the text to expand to the full width of the screen. Presently the media query is removing the float, so I know the query  is working in general, but the width:auto does not seem to be working at all, the text stays within the percentage defined in .column .two-thirds and the .column .third. Am I not handling the width attribute correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Worked with a colleague to figure this out. The problem was with the way I combined the `.column` and the `.(width percentage)` class selectors in my style sheet. By separating the `.(width percentage)` selector from the `.column` selector, the media query could then properly set the `with:auto` when the browser was at the specified max-width.